# Inject Spring @Value into Camel Unit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a set of tests which are failing because the `@Value` injection from `application.properties` is injecting nulls - i.e. they are not being found by the application when unit tests are executed.

Here are my tests:

```
public class CamelRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(
                    "./src/test/resources/application.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

        return properties;
    }

//.... Tests
```

This raises a `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`. How do I annotate the test to inject the values from `application.properties`?

Comment: Did you try creating `application.properties` in resources folder under test?

Comment: Yes there is an application.properties in the test folder

Comment: Writing these annotations on your test class should be enough `@ContextConfiguration(...)` and `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`